# UML Class Diagram: Object passed through constructor relationship?

Tags: java, class, object, uml

Suppose I have a class like this in Java:

```
public class ClassA{
     public ClassA(ClassB b){
          // do some operations or get some values etc. from ClassB b
```

ClassB is passed to ClassA **through its constructor. (not a method)** Is this relationship considered a dependency or some form of association? If we were to assume that there is no ClassB attribute in ClassA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would normally be a dependency or 'uses' relationship.  Association implies a 'has-a' relationship.

Answer (score 1):

If an instance of ClassA keeps the passed instance of ClassB, then model as an association. Otherwise, model as a dependency.